# setting an array element with a sequence error

Tags: python

**2nd Edit**

This is how a "stokes_line" is generated:

```
os.system('pdv -t %s > temp.txt ' % epoch_name)
    stokes_line = np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', usecols=3, dtype=[('stokesI','float')],     skip_header=1)

os.system('vap -nc "mjd" %s >> mjd.txt' % new_y[i])
stokes_list[b] = stokes_line
```

"pdv" is a command from another programme which generated some numbers used in the "stokes_line".

stokes_list just gets a new stokes_line added too each in a loop each time.

**EDIT:**

A stokes_line is created with a numpy.genfromtxt command (and so extracts from a txt file) and is made up of floats and they look like this:

> [(0.00126596,) (0.000621272,) (0.00058694,) ..., (0.0015368,)
>   (0.000926448,) (7.95851e-05,)]

A bunch of them together make up a stokes_list, and each stokes_line is made up of the same number of floats.

Is the problem because the genfromtxt is not creating a list which would be all square brackets, but something else (is it called a sequence)??

---

I wrote a python code which worked find on my laptop (python version 2.7.3), but it doesn't seem to run on my university desktop (python version 2.5.2).

I don't think that showing lots of the code here will be useful, but the error message is on the second of these two lines:

```
os.system('vap -nc "mjd" %s >> mjd.txt' % new_y[i])
stokes_list[b] = stokes_line
```

Where "vap" is a command from another programme which returns some values. Anyway, the crux of the matter is that I get the following error message ONLY when I run on the older version of Python:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Now I did a little research, and people say that the problem is due to incompatible lengths of lists of some such - but if that was the case, why does it work fine when I run it on my newer version of Python.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: You will need to show code that explains what `stokes_list` and `stokes_line` are.

Comment: oh okay I clicked the link now. Sorry. I'll go through my old questions and accept some answers.

Comment: How it _looks like_ doesn't describe what it is. Post some more code; specifically where you are generating `stokes_line` and `stokes_list`.

Comment: Instead of feeding us piecemeal bits of your code without proper indendation; post the entire thing at once so we don't have to keep asking for the same thing.

Comment: If I posted the whole code, it would confuse the issue. I was trying to be helpful by focussing on the part of the code that causes the problem. I fixed it myself - for anyone else - the problem was that genfromtxt was creating a 'structured array' or 'record array' which the older version of python didn't like putting in a list. I just removed the "dtype" stuff and it become a regular array.

Comment: Answer your own question and then mark your answer accepted so the question is closed.

Answer (score 3):

`.format`, the [`Formatter` class](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) was added in 2.6.

`os.system('vap -nc "mjd" %s >> mjd.txt' % new_y[i])` should work.

Comment: Sorry sorry - I originally had that in, but I changed it because someone told me that it wouldn't work. I just forgot to delete it here - I will edit now. But the problem is the same.

Comment: You need to update the original question as BrenBarn suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `np.genfromtxt(…, usecols=3, dtype=[("stokesI","float")])`, you're constructing a structured array with only one field (`"stokesI"`). Of course, when you print the array, this structure appears:

```
[(0.00126596,) (0.000621272,) (0.00058694,) ..., (0.0015368,) (0.000926448,) (7.95851e-05,)]
```

Each item is a `np.void` consisting of a named float field.

Looks a bit wasteful, you could probably simplify your expression as :

```
np.genfromtxt(…,usecols=3, dtype=float)
```

You then get:

```
[  1.26596000e-03   6.21272000e-04   5.86940000e-04 ...  1.53680000e-03
   9.26448000e-04   7.95851000e-05]
```

The probable reason why it apparently fails on an older version of Python is that you're using an older version of NumPy, like 1.4 or 1.5. There have been some improvements on the construction of `ndarrays` since (better handling of generators, automatic conversion from strings…)